# redirection urls does not work

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I come here asking for help. I developped with codeigniter framework. 
My problem is the redirect URLs. In my route I have a controller by default 'admin / user' on my local site it works without problems on my server but nothing appears remote.

codeigniter 2.0. in my config / routes.php ago it

```
$ route ['default_controller'] = 'admin / user '; 
$ route ['404_override'] = '';
```

And my controller folder structure is as follows controller ----> Admin ------> (user.php / compagnie.php / gare.php .....)

admin is a folder.

And my .htaccess file I have the following content:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! F 
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -d 
RewriteRule. * Index.php / $ 0 [PT, L]
```

THE real problem is that on my local server is no problem but on my remote server it does not display anything.

but if I change `$routes ['default_controller'] = 'welecome'`; it works on the server and nothing is displayed locally.

Help me please !!!!!

Comment: your htaccess is pretty badly formatted. if that's literally what you have, you shouldn't even be able to get your site at all, because that htaccess will cause 500 server errors before php ever has a chance to fire up.

Comment: what do you propose?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with:

```
$ route ['default_controller'] = 'admin / user '; 
$ route ['404_override'] = '';
```

Change to:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "admin/user"; 
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

And

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! F 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT, L]
```

Comment: hi !!! I just made the change and send to the server. Néamoins nothing has changed

Comment: Indeed on the remote server I put all the content in a service record. So url is: 'services.econsulting.bf';. So <pre> $config ['base_url'] = 'econsulting.bf/services </ pre>; ???

Comment: @VeeeneX The `!` at the rewrite rules are still wrong.